# Can't install xserver-xorg-video-intel

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, intel

I have been having some issues on my PC, I posted about this problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/957241/736807) about three days ago, but still haven't got any solution; so I decided to try to fix it myself...

The thing is I found out that didn't even had an intel driver installed in the first place, as you can see from my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/956759/736807), when I tried to switch to modesetting. Modesetting was enabled from the very beginning, I didn't have to switch...

So, I tried to switch back to the old xserver-xorg-video-intel driver to see if that fixes the distortion issue...

I got the following messages when I tried installing:

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
[sudo] password for sakib: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-20
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do now? It's a total mystery why I don't have Intel driver installed but modesetting instead; this didn't happened when I used Mint, by default I had Intel and then I switched to modesetting...

And now this!

**Added this paragraph after editing:** I found [this](https://tjaalton.wordpress.com/2016/07/23/intel-graphics-gen4-and-newer-now-defaults-to-modesetting-driver-on-x/) article that says that modesetting has been enabled by default for Gen4 Intel Graphics and newer...

Someone please guide me through this...

Thanks in advance...

Here's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` if it helps:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` then `sudo apt update` then try to install again

Comment: @George No result... same problem!

Comment: Ok run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Ran it... there wasn't any output... then tried to install again, and the same error!

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @Olimjon I put the output in my main post above, it's too long for a comment!

Comment: I think that, everything is right with your PPA list. So, you need try to install dependencies recursively. Like `sudo apt install xorg-video-abi-20` and this error happens again try to  install its dependencies. Eventually you will find conflicting package. *Note: It may take longer time*

Comment: It looks like you've been messing around quite a lot, thank to lots of bad advice from the site you've linked to. We also don't know which distro is in use, and what has been removed and added. For example, xserver-xorg-video-intel is installed by default in Ubuntu, but you don't have it, and, incidentally, that site suggests to remove it. Under these circumstances, I am not sure what you want from us.

Comment: @Olimjon The whole point of install xserver-xorg-video-intel is to see that it solves [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/957241/736807) issue; since modesetting is by default the graphcis driver, I honestly don't intend to change it. But no one has looked over my problem after three days...!

Comment: @mikewhatever xserver-xorg-video-intel wasn't installed by default, trust me! If it was then I'd have known! As I said(and if you read [my earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/q/956759/736807) I didn't even switch to modesetting, it was already enabled which I found out after I updated `inxi`...
My whole intention, as for now, is to solve [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/957241/736807), that's why I was trying to install xserver-xorg-video-intel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing a wrong thing. You can't install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` on Ubuntu with a HWE stack.

The package is `xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04` and it should be already installed by default.