# Switch driver to modesetting for improved OpenGL support?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, opengl, nomodeset

I switched to Lubunutu because I read it offers better OpenGL support to run emulators (Via Batocera.Linux) I found the following post from `@thefallenrat` re. switching to 'modesetting'

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/problems-with-opengl-2-1-and-gma-3150/28273

I am having some trouble

Here is my output from `inxi -CGS`

```
levelup@levelup:~$ inxi -CGS
System:    Host: levelup Kernel: 4.15.0-29-generic i686 bits: 32
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 T7200 (-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           clock speeds: max: 2000 MHz 1: 1083 MHz 2: 1126 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Mobile 945GM/GMS 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: intel (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1024x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
           version: 1.4 Mesa 18.0.5
```

I tried following the steps: `sudo mhwd -r pci video-intel`

but I must have entered the command incorrectly:

```
sudo: mhwd: command not found
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The link you have posted is for Manjaro Linux which is not Ubuntu so its commands will be different and that is why the removal of the Intel driver failed.    Look at this instead:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/956759/changing-driver-into-modesetting

Comment: ok thanks, I followed the set up via the link removing the Intel driver, it seems my card (GMA 950) is unsupported as it booted to a black screen. Reinstalling Lubuntu now, it was a fresh install so no big deal. Now to find another way to improve OpenGL

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I followed a guide found via a link Terrance provided:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

I uninstalled the Intel Driver to fallback on modesetting with:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Unfortunately my card (GMA 950) is unsupported and with no driver the desktop would not load. If I find another way to improve OpenGL support I will report back

Comment: Yes this topic is old but if someone wants to reverent that change it can be simply achieved by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`. However, probably this cannot be done so easily because there is no longer any working X server present. In that case just boot up by adding the number `3` to the grub parameters after `quiet splash` (manual edit). This will enable a boot to the command line where it is possible to login with username and password.